# Correct data for realm decimal128 data type

Tags: javascript, realm, mongodb-realm

I'm storing currency data in mongodb-realm.

This is my schema:

```
const Products = {

  name: "Products",

  properties: {

      _id: "objectId",
      price: {type: "decimal128", default:"3.1" },

   }
 }
```

When running my app I'm getting this error:
**[Error: Property must be of type 'decimal128', got (3.1)]**

I've tried other data like 0, 0.0, 0.2, "3.2"  but it keeps showing an error.

What should be the correct data format for the decimal128 data type in realm?

Comment: Did you try `price: {type: "decimal128", default: 3.1 },`   (no quotes)

Comment: @Jay I've tried it and it doesn't work

Comment: I will point you to the [Define Schema](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/examples/define-a-realm-object-model/#define-a-default-property-value) guide so you can ensure your code matches what's in the guide.

Comment: @Jay I'd already studied that guide and it shows no example code on setting the decimal128 type.

What I need here is an example code that works on how to set the data on the decimal128 type because I've tried so many data options and read all the docs but they can't show me how to do this